# Can SSH in but not out of docker container: network unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, docker, containers

Real docker noob here, trying to get an ubuntu container that can be accessed via SSH.

I'm using an image using [this dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) and building & running it with

```
docker build -t sshable ~/PATH/" and "docker run --name test -t sshable
```

I can ssh out to the host and a VM on it just fine as well as other containers running the same image.  However, when I try to `ssh IP_ADDR` from the host where IP_ADDR is the IP address given as "inet addr" in eth0 for the container (when using ifconfig) it can't, saying `ssh: connect to host IP_ADDR port 22: Network is unreachable`.  I can also ping out from the containers, but not into them as it times out.  Is the host not on the bridge network and if so how do I get it on?

Comment: The title of your post contains "ssh" and "docker". I just want to point out this article, wrote by a Docker engineer: _[If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)_

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ docker run --name test -p 22:22 sshable
```

Or also you can check the mapped docker port

```
$ docker run --name test sshable
$ docker port sshable 22
0.0.0.0:49154
```

And then you can ssh as root on the container's IP address on port 49154 (in this case)

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.2 -p 49154
```

Comment: I have done this and it still gives the same error that the network is unreachable.  I can't use  the host's port 22 since it claims that it is "already in use," so I have tried with some other pots such as 49154 2222 etc. and tried to ssh through them with no avail.  I have also tried exposing ALL the ports and simply pinging the container, which also fails for the same reasons.  Gonna add that I'm running docker directly on mac El Capitan using the native virtualization from xhyve, NOT the docker default VM on virtualbox.  Running version 1.12.0-rc4-beta20 (build:10404).

Answer (score 0):

When you're running the container with

```
docker run --name test -t sshable
```

this container exposes port 22, but doesn't attach to any ports on the host machine. This means that if you launch another container like

```
docker run -it ubuntu:14.04
```

you'll be able to ssh from this ubuntu container to yours. But if you're running Docker from inside a VM, you won't be able to ssh from outside the VM into your container. For that you need your ssh container to be attached to some port on that VM

```
docker run --name test -p 22:22 sshable
```

Now you'll be able to ssh into this container using `ssh <vm-ip>`.

Comment: I have done this and it still gives the same error that the network is unreachable. I can't use the host's port 22 since it claims that it is "already in use," so I have tried with some other pots such as 49154 2222 etc. and tried to ssh through them with no avail. I have also tried exposing ALL the ports and simply pinging the container, which also fails for the same reasons. Gonna add that I'm running docker directly on mac El Capitan using the native virtualization from xhyve, NOT the docker default VM on virtualbox. Running version 1.12.0-rc4-beta20 (build:10404).

Comment: Have you tried running `docker ps` to see on what port of the host, the container was attached to, and then tried sshing to that port?

Comment: Yes I have.  0.0.0.0:49154->22/tcp under "PORTS".  I have done ssh root@172.17.0.2 -p 49154 (that's 172... is the ip).  It fails for the exact same "network is unreachable" error.